# Datastudio :: showing people that doesnt fill the google form (daily check in issues)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, looker-studio

I'm pretty new to dataStudio and I'm trying to build a simple dashboard to track daily check in for students. The thing is, i want to show table report on datastudio based on students that doesnt fill the form on that day.

and i already figure out a few possible solution,

1. i've created another sheets on responses files, to show if the student fill the form or not in several range of date
   [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2FYQ.png), and a will filtered this into a new table that will be shown on data studio using date range filter. but i have difficulties because the date range filter only filter on row, not on column (dimensions)
2. i have quite a lot of students, so after several month the table will bulk up and do some massive processing lag upon opening. Maybe there are alternative way to do this more properly instead?

i dont know if i can solve this case using script, im trying to using js to solve this. still strugling, maybe you can give an advice, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are right, Data Studio is filtering on rows not on columns.
The best way would be to unpivot your table in Big Query.

- Connecting google sheets to Big Query: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9702507?hl=en
- Unpivot in Big Query:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unpivot_operator

and see the example:

```
SELECT * FROM Produce
UNPIVOT(sales FOR quarter IN (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4))
```

with Q1 to Q4 would be your dates in the first row.